# How do I duplicate this CURL request within nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, https

I am trying to duplicate the following CURL request within nodejs using [request-promise](https://github.com/tyabonil/request-promise) (eventually, I need to use promises so I would prefer this method):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=[API Key]" -H "Accept: application/vnd.moonclerk+json;version=1" https://api.moonclerk.com/customers
```

The following code snippet shows my attempt:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var querystring = require('querystring');

//this is what I think is causing me trouble
var bodyHeaders = querystring.stringify({
    "Authorization": "Token token=[token taken out in code snippet]",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.moonclerk+json;version=1"
});

var options = {
    uri: 'https://api.moonclerk.com/customers',
    method: 'GET',
    body: bodyHeaders
};

var cb = function () {
    return function (response) {
        console.log("response: ", response);//this should spit out the JSON text I'm looking for
    }
}

rp(options).then(cb())
```

But I am getting `Possibly unhandled StatusCodeError: 401 - HTTP Token: Access denied.` in the nodejs console as a response.  What's the issue here?

PS -- Note that my uri is an HTTPS (i.e., 'https://api.moonclerk.com/customers'); is this what's causing the problem?

Comment: You should probably define `bodyHeaders` before using that variable to define `options`.

Comment: Good suggestion; however, after correcting for this I still get the same error printed in my original post :(

Comment: Can you update your code to reflect these changes?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't post as an answer because I was pretty sure that wouldn't completely solve it.  Seemed like a good start to help others that wanted to answer, though.

Comment: This site automatically converts a cURL request to a node request. curl.trillworks.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass HTTP headers in the request body, server can't recognize them there. See https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers for correct usage of the request library.

```
var options = {
    // ...
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Token token=[token taken out in code snippet]",
        "Accept": "application/vnd.moonclerk+json;version=1"
    }
});
```